# ComboBoxText in Glade / GTK+3 / Python - disappears when displayed 2nd time

Tags: application-development, python, gtk, glade

I'm trying to implement a drop down list in an Ubuntu app using Glade (GTK+3) and Python. I can get the ComboBoxText to display, populated with strings. However when I close the window it is contained in and then re-open it, the combobox is not there, just a completely blank window.

I added the ComboBoxText widget in question to a window in Glade. I then added this code in my Python programme:

```
def on_button_edit_clicked(self, widget):
    """ display list of events already stored, and allow deletion """   

    self.combo = self.builder.get_object('combo_box')
    self.store = Gtk.ListStore(str)

    self.store.append(['hello'])
    self.store.append(['goodbye'])
    self.combo.set_model(self.store)

   event_editor = self.builder.get_object("event_editor")
   event_editor.show()
```

I even tried destroying the widget to see if that helps:

```
def on_event_editor_destroy(self, widget):
    self.combo.destroy()
    self.store = Gtk.ListStore(str)
    self.combo.set_model(self.store)
```

EDIT:

I have since tried some alternative code, that included a CellRendererText object, but still no luck.

These are my sources (unfortunately I can't link to them all as I don't have enough of a reputation):

I created a Gtk.ListStore(), then I created a Gtk.CellRendererText(), then I created a Gtk.ComboBox(). This was all in-line with example 13.3 [here](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/combobox.html).

Nothing works. When I open the combobox window a 2nd time, it is just a blank window. Can anyone help please?

Comment: You could try to ask such question since it is programming oriented at Stack Overflow. Also check this "http://gnipsel.com/glade/python06.html for more information. A quick reminders, did you check if 'combo_box' is the name for the combobox used in Glade? Did you added it in the layout manager?

Comment: Hi Stef, I already asked on Stackoverflow, no response :(

Comment: Where is the "layout manager" you speak of?

Comment: You can check [here](https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/layout.html) about layout manager which is responsible for placing widgets on a window.

Comment: How are you calling the combobox window?  Are you instantiating a new class each time or using show, hide methods? Can you post more code?

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies with the Window.

You should implement a callback for the ['delete-event'](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-delete-event) signal of the Window widget.

```
def on_event_editor_delete_event(self, widget, event):
    self.event_editor.hide()
    return True
```

This callback hides the Window and returns True so the event isn't propagated further (i.e. the Window isn't destroyed, including your ComboBox).